Why does the UDP multicast receiver need to bind to the port which the sender sendto?
I created a multicast sender and receiver, where the sender sends messages to 239.255.0.1:54321. It works well.
The receiver's steps are as follows:

Create a socket
Bind to 239.255.0.1:54321
Join the multicast group 239.255.0.1
Use recvfrom to receive messages

My question is, in a cross-machine communication scenario, how can the sender ensure that the receivers have not occupied port 54321?
I do not want the sender and receiver to both statically configure port 54321; I want this port to be dynamically discovered by the receiver through a service discovery mechanism.
Port 54321 is randomly chosen by sender. After that the Service Discovery tells the receiver multicast dest ip:port. In such a case, the multicast receiver may not be able to bind to port 54321 because another program may have already occupied this port.
Is there any way to avoid binding to the multicast_port on the reader side?
I tried connect(), bind() and join_multicast_group, changing their orders, but It seems no work.

You can pick a destination port to use and leave the source port to be randomly chosen. The source and destination ports do not need to be the same port number. For example, when you browse a web site with HTTP, your source port will be randomly chosen, but the destination port will be 80. There are three ranges of ports. Check the Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry and read the Note at the top.

@RonMaupin Thank you for your response. I'd like to clarify my question: I have multiple topics, all of which use multicast communication. I want the port number in the multicast address to be dynamically allocated, rather than pre-arranged between the sender and receiver. In the example, 54321 is such a randomly assigned port number, but it seems that it does not account for whether other machines are already using port 54321.

That is not how the client/server world works, and it is not how multicast works. Remember that there are specific ranges of multicast groups addresses used for different things. The same hold true for ports. How would the world work if web server ports are dynamically chosen. That is why you have specific ports tied to specific functions. The source port can, and normally should be, be dynamically chosen, but the application needs to know the destination port beforehand.

@RonMaupin Oh, I get it. Thank you very much.

You can still reuse the service port if all individual sockets coordinate in setting the SO_REUSEPORT setsockopt() option. This ensures that each unique (address, port) pair can communicate, even though port is the same. However, everything fails if a single socket binds to the port, whatever the address, without setting the option
